# parsing a phone number in a text with regex

Tags: xml, regex, parsing

I want to parse phone numbers from many countries around the world using a regex I need the phone numbers I can come in many different ways and need to catch them all.

Examples.

> 00212 23254324
>
> +212 324324324
>
> 232 2 121 343
>
> 234/2354323
>
> 122 232 23 213
>
> 3123-321-321

With bars, spaces, dashes.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to look once more at the formatting of your question, personally I can't tell all the phone numbers there apart. Secondly, "many countries" is a very vague definition, what countries? what kind of phone numbers? is there always a country-prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the fact that there are numerous telephone number formats with different separators, different prefixes and symbols, I don't think that regex can really match all of those cases (there are a lot more cases than you have listed there).
If you want to validate them, I suggest you count the digits (ignoring symbols and separators) and check if there are enough digits to form a valid phone number.
This way is much more easier to store them or convert them in your format :  you can extract all the digits from the number and then format the number in what way you want.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to parse the phone numbers so that you can reject invalid ones? That seems likely to reject as many good values as it rejects bad ones, given the variety that exists around the world (although not present in your list, there are I believe some countries that allow letters A-Z in their phone numbers!)